Sending Hex data Over Mqtt in modbus protocol
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

# MQTT broker details
broker = "test.mosquitto.org"
port = 1883
topic = "M66_Rx"

# Modbus RTU Frame as a list of hex values
modbus_hex = [0x11, 0x03, 0x01, 0x02, 0x01, 0x04, 0xe7, 0x59]

# Convert the list of hex values to a byte array
modbus_bytes = bytes(modbus_hex)

# MQTT client setup
client = mqtt.Client()

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    if rc == 0:
        print("Connected to MQTT broker")
    else:
        print(f"Failed to connect to MQTT broker, return code {rc}")

    def on_publish(client, userdata, mid):
        print(f"Message published with mid={mid}")

        client.on_connect = on_connect
        client.on_publish = on_publish

# Connect to MQTT broker
client.connect(broker, port)

# Start the MQTT client loop in a non-blocking manner``
client.loop_start()

# Send the Modbus RTU frame as a single byte array`
try:
    client.publish(topic, modbus_bytes)
    print("Payload being sent:", modbus_bytes.hex())
    print("Modbus RTU frame sent")
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    # Handle the user interrupt to stop the script gracefully
    print("Interrupted by user")

# Disconnect from MQTT broker
client.disconnect()
client.loop_stop()

print("Script finished")

Above code sent the Modbus_hex array to mqtt as a query, but whenever i put 0x00 in between query it will not sent other bytes after 0x00 and also I have to put 0x00 at the last to terminate the query so how can I use 0x00 in between query without termination?
`

Your code works fine for me (with a 0x00 added in the middle of the array). What are you subscribing with? 0x00 is often used to mark the end of a string, so some tools may not output this correctly; I used MQTTX set to display the data as Hex. Note that you are not "sending hex", you are just sending binary data.

Please show how you "put 0x00 in between query". It's not clear what you mean, to me, at least.

Edit the question to explain what you are subscribing with and what options you are using e.g. if mosquitto_sub are you using the -F flag to set a formatter? Any tool that treats payloads as strings will terminate on a null (0x00)
